# Ocaml pattern match against data constructor independently of its arity

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to pattern match against the just the constructor that is independent of constructor arity? Sometimes in a pattern match I only care about the constructor and not the data associated with it.

My concern is that when I change the arity of a constructor in an ADT, I have to go through and change all of my pattern matches, even ones that discard all the "fields" (what's the right term?) on the data constructor.

Suppose I have an ADT with multiple constructors

```
(* time * message *)
type log_message = 
    Warning of float * string
  | Error of float * string
```

and I want to inspect a value of this type, but only care about the constructor I have to write something like

```
let is_error_message x = match x with
    | Warning _, _ -> false
    | Error _, _ -> true
```

If later I want to go back and add a severity field to warning, giving me

```
type log_message =
   Warning of float * string * int
 | Error of float * string
```

I have to add a new wildcard to the pattern in `is_error_message` to satisfy the type checker.

```
let is_error_message x = match x with
    | Warning _, _, _ -> false
    | Error _, _ -> true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type definition

```
type log_message = 
  | Warning of float * string
  | Error of float * string
```

means that both constructors (`Warning` and `Error`) do not accept two arguments, but rather a product (i.e. tuple) of them. So you instatiate as follows:

```
Warning (4.0, "you better be warned")
```

When performing pattern matching on an instance of this variant, you could just use `_` to specify a tuple of arbitrary length (if you don't care about the parameters passed to the constructor):

```
type log_message =
  | Warning of float * string
  | Error of float * string;;

let is_error_message x = match x with
  | Warning _ -> false
  | Error _ -> true;;

is_error_message (Warning (2.0, "totally not an error"));;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: I think I meant to say `Warning of (float * string)` &c ... for a multi-parameter constructor instead of a unary constructor taking a tuple I just messed up the syntax... (and then didn't realize why `Warning _ _` wasn't valid). What you're saying's totally correct though so I don't want to just silently fix up the question.

Comment: This is not correct, the arguments to a regular constructor are not a tuple. The reason that `_` can match multiple arguments is because that has been added as a feature to cover this use case.

Comment: @gsg which version was that added in?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: the changelog mentions it being added in Caml Special Light 1.13, early in 1996.

Comment: @gsg it appears you are right, indeed. 2Gregory you might find this interesting - https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/constructors-with-several-arguments/764